# My ubuntu 14.04 is stuck in log-in loop when I try to log-in to Desktop. My login password does work at terminal but can not open the encrypted folder

Tags: 14.04, boot, login, password, encryption

I can mount the encrypted hard drive but can not access the encrypted home folder. When I try to login to my desktop, it dose process a few (2) seconds and goes back to login screen. How can I login or recover data?

Answer (score 0):

That may mean session in your account corrupted. I'd go to VT1 (Alt-Ctl-F1) to see if you can log in. If you have other accounts, test them too. 
Another explanation might be network identity problem.
If you can log in VT1 AS yourself or as root, create another user account and see if you can log in when you go back to login (Alt-Ctl-F7).